# Testcafe matching text with nested Link element

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to match the expected innerText of a paragraph with a text mock in an testcafe e2e test. The expected text is supposed to contain links (formed with react Link tags).

```
await browser.expect((await Component.method).statement).eql('this is the mock text');
```

But when the test is run the inner texts of these links are replaced by [object object]. As a result the test fails.

`'AssertionError: this is [object object] text'. to deeply equal 'this is the mock text'`

I will appreciate some insight on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, I see that you try to compare the statement "((await Component.method).statement)" with the expected string.
Then, TestCafe converts the statement to a string using a common way. I suggest you convert the statement to a string at your discretion and after that compare the actual string with the expected one.